# Proxy hosted in IIS with NTLM, how can I enable single sign on?

Tags: iis, proxy, windows-authentication, ntlm

I have a forward proxy hosted in IIS with windows authentication enabled. Firefox is set up to use the proxy. Problem is, I don't know what to do with `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris`. Apparently, firefox doesn't realize that whenever I go to any site, I'm actually authenticating to the proxy, not the site itself, and it always asks for a username and password. If I add some sites to the trusted uris list, they work fine, but I obviously can't add the entire internet to it. It also seems like a pretty serious security risk should someone disable the proxy at some point. Adding the proxy itself to the list doesn't seem to do anything.

So, how can I set this up so that firefox will automatically supply credentials to the proxy?